# Get value from map in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class :

```
Category(val name : String? = null, val products: Map<Product,Boolean> = mutableMapOf())
```

and this class is used in an activity in the map:

```
private var categoriesAndProducts = mutableMapOf<Category, Boolean>()
```

And my problem is when I have a name of the category, I need to go inside Category class and then outside to obtain category's boolean value. Problem is I don't know how to get this boolean value when I am inside. Like how to go back higher in this hierarchy and get that value.

Comment: Having that boolean value as a parameter in the Category class is not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correct, you want to find a `Category` within `categoriesAndProducts` based on `Category.name`. Having this `Category` (which is the key), you then want to get it's `Boolean` value from `categoriesAndProducts`.

You can do this by filtering first for keys that are matching the Category name:

```kotlin
val key: Category? = categoriesAndProducts.keys.firstOrNull {
  it.name == "someName"
}

categoriesAndProducts[key] // returns null when key is null
```

You could write an extension function that helps you accessing the Category key based on a name:

```kotlin
fun Map<Category, Boolean>.findByName(name: String): Boolean? {
  val key: Category? = keys.firstOrNull { it.name == name }
  return get(key)
}

categoriesAndProducts.findByName("someName") // returns boolean
```

Comment: Actually I want to get boolean from this first map: mutableMapOf<Category, Boolean>(), but only thing I know is name which is inside Category class, as you wrote Category.name

Comment: I got it. I slightly updated my answer. This gives you the value (Boolean) from `categoriesAndProducts` for a given name (String).